# Redirect query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
Rewrite **
www.thaippt.com/_property.php?section=5&id=553
```

to

```
www.thaippt.com/property/5/553/
```

with code

```
RewriteRule ^property\/([^/]*)/([^/]*) /_property.php?section=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

It works but I need to redirect query string.

If I go to "`_property.php?section=5&id=553"`

I need to redirect to `"/property/5/553/"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use this rule above the other one.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ /+_property\.php\?section=([^\s&]+)&id=([^\s&]+)
RewriteRule ^ /property/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

Let me know how this works for you.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/28WvcpMQ   But  I need someting like this. Could you please help me ?

Comment: Can you ask a new question please.

Comment: Is possible?
Original URL: www.thaippt.com/_property.php?section=9&id=617

Desired destination URL: www.thaippt.com/property/แมนชัน/617/